# Specific value of $\zeta(3/2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Is anything known about the value of $$\zeta(3/2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}?$$ It is a classical result that $\displaystyle \zeta(2)= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\zeta(3)$ has been shown to be irrational by Roger Apéry in 1979.

Do we even know if $$\zeta(3/2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ is an irrational number or not? Is it  true that $$\zeta(3/2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}=\frac{a}{b}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{n^{3/2}\binom{2n}{n}}?$$ Not sure if Apéry's proof can be adapted here since I haven't read it.

Comment: It's been studied, but not enough to be [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function). [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) list includes it, mentioning its roles in physics (one is quantified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose–Einstein_condensate#Critical_temperature)) and linking to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A078434). I think your specific mathematical queries about it may make this question better suited to [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the links! I should have checked the Wiki, didn't think I could find it there!

Answer (score 4):

By no means an answer but an extended comment. I should also preface I am an amateur mathematician with no formal education. Following Wikipedia's entry for the Riemann zeta function we have the following functional equation:
$$
\zeta(s)=2^{s}\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\pi s/2\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)\label{a}\tag{1}
$$
Suppose $s=3/2.$ Via direct substitutions I can rewrite RHS side of $\ref{a}$ explicitly as
$$
2^{3/2}\cdot\pi^{3/2-1}\cdot\sin\left(3\pi/4\right)\cdot\Gamma(1-3/2)\cdot\zeta(1-3/2);\label{b}\tag{2}
$$
which after plugging in yields,
$$
2^{3/2}\cdot\pi^{3/2-1}\cdot2^{1/2}\cdot(-1)\cdot2^{1}\cdot\pi^{1/2}\cdot\zeta(-1/2).\label{c}\tag{3}
$$
After regrouping and gathering like terms one can reduce $\ref{c}$ to,
$$
2^{3/2-1/2+1}\cdot\pi^{3/2-1+1/2}\cdot\zeta(-1/2);\label{d}\tag{4}
$$
which is equal to,
$$
-4\pi\zeta(-1/2).\label{f}\tag{5}
$$
And so
$$
\zeta(3/2)=-4\pi\zeta(-1/2), \label{g}\tag{6}
$$
Observe:
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdot\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(-1/2)}=\pi. \label{h}\tag{7}
$$
Surely $-1/4$ is rational. If each quantities $\zeta(3/2)$ and $\zeta(-1/2)$ are rational then $\pi$ is rational, a contradiction. Subsequently at least one of $\zeta(3/2)$ or $\zeta(-1/2)$, is irrational.

---

Also following the geometric definition of $\pi$, namely as the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter, one has
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdot\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(-1/2)}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{C}{2r}. \label{i}\tag{8}
$$
A quick cancelation shows that,
$$
12.56637061\ldots=-\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(-1/2)}=2\cdot\left(\frac{C}{r}\right). \label{j}\tag{9}
$$
It's certainly NOT reasonable to interpret the LHS of $\ref{j}$ as twice the ratio of a circle's circumference to its radius - but evidently it is. For example, suppose a circle has radius 4.8, and subsequently circumference 30.1593... then
$$
2\cdot\frac{30.1593\ldots}{4.8}=12.56637061\ldots
$$

---

We use the fact that $\sin(3\pi/4)=2^{-1/2}$ and $\Gamma(1-3/2)=(-1)\cdot2^{1}\cdot\pi^{1/2}.$