# What does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt n}$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

By the integral test $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt n}$ converges.

What number does it converges to?

Comment: I do not think there is a closed form solution for that sum.

Comment: That would be $\zeta(3/2)$

Comment: There are only approximates for this. Somewhere around 2.61, from 10 seconds of Desmos.

Comment: There is a reason why students are asked to determine convergence or divergence of all sorts of infinite series, but much less often are asked to _evaluate_ a convergent series.  As just one instance, you probably know now how to tell whether $ \ \sum_{n \ = \ 1}^{\infty} \ \frac{1}{n^p} \ \ , $ with $ \ p \ $ being an odd positive integer, converges.  _No one_ knows an exact value for _any_ of those sums...

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I understand it now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924124/specific-value-of-zeta3-2 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377534/value-of-zeta3-2

Comment: @boojum An odd integer greater than one, you mean

Comment: @MarkSaving  I did say "whether" the sum converges (and values would only be applicable for the convergent ones)...