# What is the limit of $\sum_{k=1} ^n 1/(k \sqrt k)$ if $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: limits, roots

I do think it diverges to infinity but i can't find a proper demonstration and without using integrals. $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1} ^n \frac {1} {k \sqrt k}$$

Comment: What's wrong with using integrals?  What techniques would you like to use to prove the result?  (And assuming my edit correctly reflected your intent, that limit converges to a finite number.  It doesn't diverge to infinity.)

Comment: What have you tried? You should post your attempts in your question. Also, why the aversion to integrals?

Comment: Isn't that $\zeta(3/2)$?

Comment: See [Cauchy Condensation test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) and [Geometric Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: @gst076923: [Yes, it is (3/2).](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%281%2F%28k*sqrt%28k%29%29+for+k%3D1+to+infinity%29)  Approximately 2.612375348685488.

Comment: The summation is just a p-series with p = 3/2 > 1.

Comment: It should hopefully be possible to use the limit comparison test with $b_k := k^{-1/2} - (k+1)^{-1/2}$, where $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges since it's a telescoping series and $k^{-1/2}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: Little or nothing seems to be known about the infinite sum, beyond the fact that it exists: see [Specific value of $\zeta(3/2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3924124) and [Value of $\zeta(3/2)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377534)

Comment: Thanks for editing my post Robert shore, this is my first time posting here so excuse my mistakes please. As for why i'm not allowed to use integrals because we haven't studied them yet so the teacher won't accept that demonstration. I realised after reading all of your answers that this sum actually does not diverge but converges, so i still have to demonstrate that it converges. I have tried comparison with other sums but i still can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not to use generalized harmonic numbers and their asymptotics ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler the limit comparison test doesn't seem to be working for me using that sum, i don't see how it could be possible.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i cannot, because i'm just trying to proove that this sum converges using a simple method that i still can't find.

Comment: @777sa OK, I posted an answer with the details of how that solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Let us apply the limit comparison test with $a_k = \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} = k^{-3/2}$ and $b_k = k^{-1/2} - (k+1)^{-1/2}$.  Then
$$\frac{b_k}{a_k} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k} \cdot \sqrt{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}} = \frac{k(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})}{\sqrt{k+1}} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{k+1} \cdot (\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k})} = \\ \frac{1}{1 + 1/k + \sqrt{1+1/k}}.$$
Therefore, $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{b_k}{a_k} = \frac{1}{2}$.  On the other hand, $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k = 1 - (n+1)^{-1/2}$ so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k = 1$ converges.  Therefore, by the limit comparison test, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ also converges.

---

An alternate proof of the limit can be gotten by an application of the mean value theorem.  Namely, if we let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, then there exists some $\xi \in (k, k+1)$ such that
$$f'(\xi) = -\frac{1}{2} \xi^{-3/2} = f(k+1) - f(k) = (k+1)^{-1/2} - k^{-1/2}.$$
However, since $k < \xi < k+1$, we see that $-\frac{1}{2} k^{-3/2} < -\frac{1}{2} \xi^{-3/2} < -\frac{1}{2} (k+1)^{-3/2}$, so $b_k = -f'(\xi) = \frac{1}{2} \xi^{-3/2}$ implies
$$\frac{1}{2} (1+1/k)^{-3/2} < \frac{b_k}{a_k} < \frac{1}{2}.$$
Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{b_k}{a_k} = \frac{1}{2}$.

(The reason I gave this alternate proof is because it's closer to the way I came up with the telescoping series to compare with in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer! It helped so much.