# On the irrationality of $\zeta(\frac{3}{2})$

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, constants

It is known that $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$Where $\zeta$ is riemann's zeta function. Usually people make $s$ an integer. But I thought of non integer values of $s$ and started with $s=\frac32$. So I wondered if $\zeta(\frac32)$ is irrational. According to wolfram alpha, this is unknown. But is there any research on the irrationality/transcendence of this number?

Comment: Googling brings up a question in mathoverflow asking about $\zeta(\frac{3}{2})$. Everyone in the comments says that just about nothing is known about the value. However the comments are from 2020, so there may have been something during the last years.

Comment: The MO question is: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377534/value-of-zeta3-2. There are a few more links there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924124/specific-value-of-zeta3-2 .

Comment: Last I checked, it is not even known if $\zeta(5)$ (or for that matter, the zeta function evaluated at any odd integer above $3$) is irrational.  I would be surprised if irrationality of $\zeta(3/2)$ has been shown.