# Is there any known method to compute $\zeta\left(\frac 3 2 \right) = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$. Using the integral test (as shown below), I was able to prove that this function does have some finite value. Is there any way to find the exact numerical value it converges to?

## Proof of Convergence

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}
This sum converges if and only if the corresponding integral converges:
\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right]_1^{\infty}\\
&=2
\end{align}
Since the integral converges to $2$ (a finite value), the sum must converge too.

## Problem

I cannot find any method to find the value of this sum, approximations are the only things I can find. Is anyone aware how I can find the value of this sum? I'm also curious if it shows up in other places in mathematics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specific value of $\zeta(3/2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924124/specific-value-of-zeta3-2) Many other posts here address this question, as does wikipedia.

Comment: Unfortunately, the conclusion of that post is $\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=4\pi\zeta\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)$ however since I have no clue about $\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ either, it does not help that much. I'm looking for an approach that evaluates it in (possibly) terms of other functions whose numerical values are easily computable. However that post does help me realize about the fact that it is quite probable that the value I am interested is irrational.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A078434 might help; It does have some formula's